# Unable to Add new user in Knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, bootstrap-modal

I am using knockoutjs to show multiple record in table using foreach loop,In the table foot 
Adduser button which allow to enter new user, in previous version of our software when user 
clicks on Adduser it shows the input fields within the tr so the user can be added. 
Now my task is to show input form in modal popup. But my problem is data-bind is in table body tag and adduser button and modal popup div is outside of table bosy tag
So it gives error like

> "Error: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Message: ReferenceError: LoginName is not defined;
>   Bindings value: value: LoginName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"

Following is code

```
<table class="report-table cstm-report-tbl" data-bind="if: CompanyId()">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Login
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <!-- ko if: $root.EditId() !== null -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Users">
        <tr>
            <!-- ko if: $root.EditId() === Id() -->
            <td><span data-bind="click: $root.Edit, text: LoginName, css: { clickable: $root.EditId() === null },  attr: {'data-target': '#myModal' + Id()}" data-toggle="modal"></span></td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: EditEmail" />
            </td>

            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko ifnot: $root.EditId() === Id() -->
            <td><span data-bind="click: $root.Edit, text: LoginName, css: { clickable: $root.EditId() === null },  attr: {'data-target': '#myModal' + Id()}" data-toggle="modal"></span></td>
            <td data-bind="text: Email"></td>
            <!-- ko if: $root.EditId() === 0 -->
            <!--<td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>-->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
        <tr class="modal fade cstm-resident-modal cstm-admin-popbox" data-bind="attr: { id: 'myModal' + Id()}" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
            <td colspan="3" class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Client Admins</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="input-wrpr">
                        <div class="label">
                            <label>Login Name</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field">
                            <input data-bind="visible: Id() === 0, value: LoginName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="text">
                            <span data-bind="visible: Id() !== 0, text: LoginName" style="display: none;"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-wrpr">
                        <div class="label">
                            <label>Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <input data-bind="value: EditEmail, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-wrpr">
                        <div class="label">
                            <label>Password</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <input data-bind="value: Password, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-wrpr">
                        <div class="label">
                            <label>Is Approved</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <input data-bind="checked: IsApproved, visible: $root.EditId() !== 0" style="display: none;" type="checkbox">
                            <span data-bind="visible: $root.EditId() === 0">N/A</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div id="InlineEditActionPanel">
                            <span class="" data-bind="click: $root.Save, css: { clickable: $root.IsValid }">Save</span>
                            <span class="clickable" data-bind="click: $root.CancelEdit" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!--<tr>
            <td class="add-user-popbx" data-bind="attr: { colspan: $root.EditId() === null ? 4 : 5 }">
                <span class="add-usr-btn" data-bind="click: $root.Add, css: { clickable: $root.EditId() === null },  attr: {'data-target': '#myModal' + Id()}" data-toggle="modal">Add new user</span>
            </td>
        </tr>-->
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>

        <tr>
            <td class="add-user-popbx" data-bind="attr: { colspan: $root.EditId() === null ? 4 : 5 }">
                <span class="add-usr-btn" data-bind="click: $root.Add, css: { clickable: $root.EditId() === null }" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Add new user</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="modal fade cstm-resident-modal cstm-admin-popbox" id="myModal2" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
            <td colspan="3" class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Client Admins</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="input-wrpr">
                        <div class="label">
                            <label>Login Name</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field">
                            <input data-bind="visible: Id() === 0, value: LoginName, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="text">
                            <span data-bind="visible: Id() !== 0, text: LoginName" style="display: none;"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-wrpr">
                        <div class="label">
                            <label>Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <input data-bind="value: EditEmail, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-wrpr">
                        <div class="label">
                            <label>Password</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <input data-bind="value: Password, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-wrpr">
                        <div class="label">
                            <label>Is Approved</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <input data-bind="checked: IsApproved, visible: $root.EditId() !== 0" style="display: none;" type="checkbox">
                            <span data-bind="visible: $root.EditId() === 0">N/A</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div id="InlineEditActionPanel">
                            <span class="clickable" data-bind="click: $root.Save, css: { clickable: $root.IsValid }">Save</span>
                            <span class="clickable" data-bind="click: $root.CancelEdit" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

following js code

```
ResPortal.Admin.MaAdmin = function () {
var maAdminViewModel = function () {
    var that = this;

    this.Busy = ko.observable(false);

    this.Companies = ko.observableArray();

    this.CompanyId = ko.observable(0);

    this.CompanyName = ko.computed(function () {
        var i;

        if (that.Busy()) {
            return "";
        }

        for (i = 0; i < that.Companies().length; i++) {
            if (that.Companies()[i].Id == that.CompanyId()) {
                return that.Companies()[i].Name;
            }
        }
    });

    this.EditId = ko.observable();

    this.Users = ko.observableArray();

    this.Add = function () {
        var newUser;

        if (that.EditId() !== null) {
            return;
        }

        newUser = {
            EditEmail: ko.observable(""),
            Email: ko.observable(""),
            Id: ko.observable(0),
            IsApproved: ko.observable(true),
            LoginName: ko.observable(""),
            Password: ko.observable("")
        };

        that.Users.push(newUser)
        that.EditId(0);
    };

    this.Edit = function (user) {
        if (that.EditId() !== null || that.EditId() === user.Id()) {
            return;
        }

        that.EditId(user.Id());
    };

    this.Save = function (user) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/SaveAdmin",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                companyId: that.CompanyId(),
                userId: user.Id(),
                login: user.LoginName(),
                email: user.EditEmail(),
                newPassword: user.Password(),
                isActive: user.IsApproved()
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        }).fail(function (data) {
            ResPortal.Helpers.notify(data.d.Message || "Server error", "error");
        }).success(function (data) {
            if (data.d.Success) {
                ResPortal.Helpers.notify(data.d.Message || "User updated", "success");

                user
                    .Email(user.EditEmail())
                    .Password("");

                if (user.Id() === 0) {
                    user.Id(data.d.Data);
                } else {
                    if (!user.IsApproved()) {
                        that.Users.remove(user);
                    }
                }

                that.CancelEdit();
            } else {
                ResPortal.Helpers.notify(data.d.Message || "Server error", "error");
            }
        });
    };

    this.CancelEdit = function () {
        var user = _.find(that.Users(), function (u) {
            return u.Id() === that.EditId();
        });

        if (user) {
            user.EditEmail(user.Email());

            if (user.Id() === 0) {
                that.Users.remove(user);
            }
        }

        that.EditId(null);
    };

    this.CompanyId.subscribe(function (value) {
        if (!value) {
            return null;
        }

        that.Busy(true);

        that.EditId(null);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/GetClientAdmins",
            data: JSON.stringify({ companyId: that.CompanyId() }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        }).fail(function (data) {
            ResPortal.Helpers.notify(data.d.Message || "Server error", "error");
        }).done(function (data) {
            var users = data.d.Data.Users;

            // Attach additional properties for editing
            _.each(users, function (user) {
                user.EditEmail = ko.observable(user.Email);
                user.Email = ko.observable(user.Email);
                user.Id = ko.observable(user.Id);
                user.IsApproved = ko.observable(user.IsApproved);
                user.LoginName = ko.observable(user.LoginName);
                user.Password = ko.observable("");
            });

            that.Users(users);

            that.Busy(false);
        });
    });

    this.IsValid = ko.computed(function () {
        var user,
            create;

        user = _.find(that.Users(), function (u) {
            return u.Id() === that.EditId();
        });

        if (!user) {
            return false;
        }

        create = user.Id() === 0;

        if (create) {
            return user.LoginName().length && user.EditEmail().length && user.Password().length;
        } else {
            return user.EditEmail().length;
        }
    });
},
    vm = new maAdminViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("AdminPanel"));

vm.Busy(true);

$.get("../Services/CompanyService.svc/GetCompanies", function (data) {
    _.each(data, function (co) {
        vm.Companies.push(co);
    });
}).fail(function (d) {
    ResPortal.Helpers.notify(["Server error", "(Click this message to close)"], "error", true);
}).always(function () {
    vm.Busy(false);
});

// Polyfills
```

};

Please help me

Comment: Show your js model.

Comment: @lorond question has been edited plz have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You have bound users to each row in `tbody` via `foreach`. But you also have same bindings to user fields inside `tfoot` that is bound to your `vm`, not to any user. And `vm` have no properties like `LoginName`, `Id` and so on.

I'm not sure how you going to user `tfoot`.

If you want to use it as edit user area, you could add currently editing user to your model:

```
this.EditUser = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    if (that.EditId() == null) {
        return null;
    }

    var user = _.find(that.Users(),
        function(u) {
            return u.Id() === that.EditId();
        });

    return user;
});
```

and bind in to `tfoot`:

```
<tfoot data-bind="if: EditUser() != null">
    <!-- ko with: EditUser -->

    <!-- rest of your html ... -->

    <!-- /ko -->
</tfoot>
```

But due to your `Add` method code you adding new users to user list and perform inline editing. In this case you could remove from `tfoot` everything but `add new user` button.

Comment: so how to bound to the Users model. I am new to knockout js and this task is making me mad. plz help